# Can't manage Exchange 2007 Room via OWA

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-web-app

I created a couple of rooms in Exchange 2007 (http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-resource-mailboxes-exchange-server-2007-part1.html)and I want to logon to OWA to manage resource settings but I can't logon to the mailboxes via OWA because of an invalid password error.  I've reset it but still no luck.  I've granted myself full permissions to the mailbox and try to access via my account but I just get a popup of my own account in the browser (ie9 and ie8).

What's going on here?

Comment: When you reset the password, you did keep the box unchecked for 'change password on next logon' right? If you have this checked, OWA fails to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

If you delegated yourself as the room mailbox admin, you will login with your own exchange account and then manage the room mailbox

`Now, the user specified in the Add-MailboxPermission cmdlet can access the Resource Mailbox. We can accomplish this using an OWA session. Open OWA using the credentials that have access to the Resource mailbox, and then click on the name of the logged user in the upper-right side of OWA and type in the name of the Resource Mailbox and click Open, as shown in Figure 13.`

Comment: I saw that step and with SP1 you can actually do it through the console instead of just the shell.  Still no dice :(